# responseXML clips XML data sent

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to `XMLHttpRequest` but have succeded updating a clock from the server using it with `GET`.

Now I need to send `POST` and receive `XML`. My `PHP` at the server is receiving posts and even sending back data in XML format, but I have a strange problem if an XML elements contains html-like code: responseXML delivers the element's text clipped from the html code to the end.

Here is the relevant code:

PHP sending XML:

```
header( 'Content-type: text/xml' );
echo '<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"   ?>'; 
echo "<posts>"; 
echo "<textblock>Block with html<br />Next line in block</textblock>"; 
echo "<inputline>input line</inputline>";
echo "</posts>";
```

Full XML response according to Firebug (notice all the data is there)

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"   ?><posts><textblock>Block with html<br />
Next line in block</textblock><inputline>input line</inputline></posts>
```

Back in the browser JS variable *received* gets "Block with html",  nothing else.      *HttpPostExch* is XMLHttpRequest

```
var received = 
HttpPostExch.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("textblock")[0].firstChild.data;
```

Next element, inputline, is available without problems. Above is with FF16, IE8 does the same. So I should be doing something wrong to include `HTML` codes in `XML`.

Any ideas why the code does that when html is present?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the first child of the `textblock` node, which is a text node with text `"Block with html"`. The behavior here is entirely expected. If you want the entire `textblock` node, use:

```
HttpPostExch.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("textblock")[0].data;
```

Comment: Sorry, no, HttpPostExch.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("textblock")[0].data doesn't define any value for the _received_ variable (I checked it). Thank you anyway.

Comment: @RickTrelles Try this: `var received = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(HttpPostExch.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("textblock")[0])`

Answer (score 0):

XML doesn't accept angled brackets in the text of the elements, so one can't send HTML text. That's an unnecessary limitation, I think. I is easy to differentiate the end of the element from HTML tags.